# SQL Join 2 tables and replace fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sort of a problem, to show it to you guys, I break it down to a little example.
To enlarge the reality aspect, lets assume that the birthdays of the customers are varying daily.
There are 2 tables, one table containing the customers and another table containing star signs.

[image: **click here to see the tables.**]

(Date format: DD-MM-YYYY, **dateofbirth data type is varchar**)

I want to match the dates of the two tables, to create a view containing the customers and the appropriate star signs, for example:   [image: **<code>ViewCustomerStarsigns</code>**]

I experimented with wildcards, joins etc. but I don't get it. I slowly lose the faith that this is generally possible, but before giving up, I am asking you guys. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Column dateOfBirth's data type?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: dateofbirth data type is varchar

Comment: You need:
1) Convert `varchar` to proper `date` with `to_date` function
2) Extract month form `date` with `date_part` function
3) Join on extracted month

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I know but this is an example, in the real database the column is varchar and does not contain birth dates.

Comment: I do not get the problem. As long as the column contains date information - you can convert them to actual `date`s. Having `date`s - you can apply postgres date math and extract any type of information from them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the column dateofbirth uses data type "varchar".  I see, i should have made a better example...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out:
I expanded the table "Starsigns":

```
date       | starsign  |
-----------+-----------+
01.01.1956 | capricorn |
-----------+-----------+
02.01.1956 | capricorn |
-----------+-----------+
03.01.1956 | capricorn |
-----------+-----------+
" " " " " " " " " " " "
-----------+-----------+
15.12.1988 |Sagittarius|
-----------+-----------+
```

Then i simply joined the two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
Join Starsigns on Starsigns.date = Customers.dateofbirth
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright... I'm going to give you the SELECT statement, which should be good enough.

You need to:

- view all customers
- pair them with their sign based on birthmonth

This requires you to cast (or start with) their birthdate to a "date" type, then extract the month. Once you've done this, you can join the tables based on month = signid (or sign month, or whatever).

[Up to date SQL Fiddle to cast from varchar to date](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cafb70/1)
OldSQLFiddle: [--ignore--](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/19f85/1)

Note that I only used one entry for each table to make my life easier and prove the concept.

My join statement is here:

```
SELECT c.last_name, c.first_name, c.birth_date, s.sign_name
FROM customers c
JOIN signs s ON s.sign_id = 
    date_part('month', to_date(c.birth_date,'DD.MM.YYYY'))
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear with this.

Additionally: [this link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html) should help you with any date formatting you may need.

Comment: @Igor Romanchenko said something similar in the comment, apparently.

Comment: hello goodguy, thank you very much for your reply! unfortunately the dateofbirth data type is varchar and not date. But now i am getting into it, maybe i can solve it tomorrow - thank you guys for your help :)

Comment: @ACKflow, That's as easy as casting the varchar to a date in the query, I'll edit my answer to show you.